# Basic JavaScript promise test with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I'm trying to get a basic promise test working with bluebird, but the result isn't what I'm expecting. I'm trying to get the "Should I be logged first? 4000" message to log to my console first, but the second console message always gets displayed first. What am I doing wrong, and what do I need to do to get the "4000" message to log before teh 2000 message?

```
function longRunningPositiveTest3() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Should I be logged first? 4000");
            resolve();
        }, 4000);
    });
}

function longRunningPositiveTest4() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log("Should I be logged first? 2000");
            resolve();
        }, 2000);
    });
}

Promise.resolve(longRunningPositiveTest3())
    .then(longRunningPositiveTest4());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling both of your functions that start the timeouts immediately. You need to pass a callback function to `then`!

Use

```
Promise.resolve(…) // some starting promise
.then(longRunningPositiveTest3)
.then(longRunningPositiveTest4);
```

or

```
longRunningPositiveTest3() // no need to wrap it in Promise.resolve() (but no harm either)
.then(longRunningPositiveTest4);
```